# How to get point location?

Tags: geometry, sharpmap, vector-layer

I load a VectorLayer which contain coordinate location point.

Now, I have a VectorLayer  and I would like to get the point location on a item of this layer in order to center a map to this point.

Is it possible ?

Comment: Do you want to center on a specific item, or just any random item, or do you want all items visible in the map view?

Comment: No just a specific item of this layer. I have the ItemID for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
var provider = vectorLayer.DataSource;
var geometry = p.GetGeometryByID(fid);
var location = geometry.Centroid.Coordinate;
//map.Center = location; 
mapBox1.Map.Center = location; 
mapBox1.Refresh();
```

Comment: Thanks. it's almots that, but the function GetGeometryByID take an integer argument which determinate the feature object ID.
In my case, I have the ID of my object, which represente the IdColumn.

Comment: The Shapefile provider derives from FilterProvider. You can assign a FilterDelegate function that evaluates the feature data for any attribute you like.
    
    p.FilterDelegate = dr => dr["IdColumn"] == IdValue;

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with sharpmap, but from the available documentation I guess you could do as follows:

1. Get the envelope of the point
2. call map.ZoomToBox(Envelope) with the envelope as a parameter.

Probably (1) can be achieved by calling something like

```
new Envelope(-9.205626, -9.123736, 38.690993, 38.740837)
```

with the point coordinates as parameters. Or maybe the Point object has a `.envelope` property.

Comment: Thanks. 
Effectivelly, for center the map, we have to set the enveloppe like you said. But, I don't know how to retrieve the enveloppe of a specific point.